# Upgraded to wildfly-24.0.0.Final & deployed EAR with this error

Tags: gradle, primefaces, wildfly, jsf-2.2, jboss-weld

I have two applications I started developing using WildFly 14.0.0.Final in 2018 & now deployed on WildFly 23.0.2.Final (April 2021).

```
MacBook-Pro-2:bin NOTiFY$ ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-23.0.2.Final

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true  --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

09:52:04,688 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final
09:52:05,687 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
09:52:05,694 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
09:52:05,795 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 23.0.2.Final (WildFly Core 15.0.1.Final) starting
```

Using JSF with PrimeFaces 10.0.3:

```
09:54:11,077 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) JSF1020: [/GoStopHandle] Configuration option 'javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS' RESET to ENABLED
09:54:11,093 INFO  [org.primefaces.webapp.PostConstructApplicationEventListener] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) Running on PrimeFaces 10.0.3
09:54:11,533 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) RESTEASY002225: Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class com.gostophandle.webservices.ApplicationConfig$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
09:54:11,602 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 92) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/GoStopHandle' for server 'default-server'
09:54:11,653 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "GoStopHandle.ear" (runtime-name : "GoStopHandle.ear")
```

However when using WildFly 24.0.0.Final + EJBs as EAR:

```
MacBook-Pro-2:bin NOTiFY$ ./standalone.sh -b 0.0.0.0 --server-config=standalone-full.xml
=========================================================================

  JBoss Bootstrap Environment

  JBOSS_HOME: /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-24.0.0.Final

  JAVA: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-15.0.2.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java

  JAVA_OPTS:  -server -Xms64m -Xmx512m -XX:MetaspaceSize=96M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman -Djava.awt.headless=true  --add-exports=java.desktop/sun.awt=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.naming/com.sun.jndi.ldap=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.security=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.management/javax.management=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.naming/javax.naming=ALL-UNNAMED

=========================================================================

09:58:51,858 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.11.0.Final
09:58:52,675 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.4.12.Final
09:58:52,682 INFO  [org.jboss.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.4.0.Final
09:58:52,785 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYSRV0049: WildFly Full 24.0.0.Final (WildFly Core 16.0.0.Final) starting
09:58:53,360 INFO  [org.wildfly.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 29) ELY00001: WildFly Elytron version 1.16.0.Final
```

When I try & deploy my EAR (WAR + JAR) I get x EJBs working:

```
10:01:05,746 INFO  [org.jboss.as.repository] (External Management Request Threads -- 1) WFLYDR0001: Content added at location /usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-24.0.0.Final/standalone/data/content/b7/23295178bb89a69a058423244b946379f8d92d/content
10:01:05,766 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "GoStopHandle.ear" (runtime-name: "GoStopHandle.ear")
10:01:06,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "GoStopHandleWAR.war")
10:01:06,640 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0207: Starting subdeployment (runtime-name: "GoStopHandleJAR.jar")
10:01:08,336 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry jaxb-core.jar in /content/GoStopHandle.ear/GoStopHandleWAR.war/WEB-INF/lib/jaxb-impl-3.0.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:01:08,608 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit
10:01:08,986 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'GoStopHandle.ear/GoStopHandleJAR.jar#goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit'
10:01:08,996 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment GoStopHandle.ear
10:01:09,006 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: goStopHandleMongoDBPersistenceUnit
    ...]
10:01:09,119 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.20.Final}
10:01:09,120 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 85) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
10:01:09,132 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-7) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.0.22.Final
10:01:09,391 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment GoStopHandleJAR.jar
10:01:09,393 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'ManufacturerEJB' in deployment unit 'subdeployment "GoStopHandleJAR.jar" of deployment "GoStopHandle.ear"' are as follows:

    java:global/GoStopHandle/GoStopHandleJAR/ManufacturerEJB!com.gostophandle.ejb.ManufacturerEJB
    java:app/GoStopHandleJAR/ManufacturerEJB!com.gostophandle.ejb.ManufacturerEJB
    java:module/ManufacturerEJB!com.gostophandle.ejb.ManufacturerEJB
    java:global/GoStopHandle/GoStopHandleJAR/ManufacturerEJB
    java:app/GoStopHandleJAR/ManufacturerEJB
    java:module/ManufacturerEJB

etc ...
```

But then I get a 'SEVERE' error:

```
10:01:11,850 INFO  [org.omnifaces.ApplicationInitializer] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Using OmniFaces version 3.11.1
10:01:11,950 INFO  [io.undertow.websockets.jsr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) UT026005: Adding programmatic server endpoint class org.omnifaces.cdi.push.SocketEndpoint for path /omnifaces.push/{channel}
10:01:11,979 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Initializing Mojarra 2.3.14.SP04 for context '/GoStopHandle'
10:01:12,349 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 96) Critical error during deployment: : java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.jboss.as.web.common.WebInjectionContainer, but class was expected
    at org.jboss.as.jsf-injection//org.jboss.as.jsf.injection.JSFInjectionProvider.invokePostConstruct(JSFInjectionProvider.java:68)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.injectImplementation(FactoryFinderInstance.java:498)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:465)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:363)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:200)
    at javax.faces.api@3.0.0.SP04//javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:279)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP04//com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.lambda$verifyFactoriesExist$0(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:303)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:948)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP04//com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:297)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP04//com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:211)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP04//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.lambda$initialize$0(ConfigManager.java:295)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP04//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:293)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.14.SP04//com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:207)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl$1.call(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:187)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:42)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1535)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.2.8.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:255)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

I'm using:

> PrimeFace (Elite) 10.0.3  Mojarra JSF 2.3.14.SP04 & OmniFaces 3.11.1
> WildFly 23.0.2.Final  Weld 3.1.5 (Final) & CDI 2.0  Java OpenJDK
> 15.0.2, Kotlin 1.5.20 Gradle (Kotlin) 7.1 MongoDB 5.0.0-rc0 Google Chrome, macOS Big Sur 11.4

Comment: i guess the problem is that you include inside your ear jars that are already provided by wildfly so there is a confict. not much info in order to find the issue. can you check which jars are included?

Comment: @Apostolos. Will "check which jars are included". Do you know what has changed with WF 23.0.2.Final -> 24.0.0.Final which could cause?

Comment: no no idea. have tested my app in both versions and i dont have any problems. so i guess it is a classpath issue where you include jars already provided by wildfly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Needed to upgrade in:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/wildfly-as/wildfly-24.0.0.Final/modules/org/jboss/as/jsf-injection/main/
```

from:

```
weld-jsf-3.1.5.Final.jar
wildfly-jsf-injection-21.0.2.Final.jar
```

to:

```
weld-jsf-4.0.1.Final.jar
wildfly-jsf-injection-24.0.0.Final.jar
```